# Pandas: Conditional partial replacing based on different columns using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

I'm not familiar with the use of dictionaries in Python in its entirety, but I believe they can come in quite handy for my issue.
Say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NATIONALITY': {0: 'Germany', 1: 'France'}, 'APPROACH': {0: 'MAEU_TEST', 1: 
'MAEU_TEST'}})
di = {'France': 'FR',
      'Germany': 'DE',
     }

df
NATIONALITY APPROACH
0   Germany MAEU_TEST
1   France  MAEU_TEST
```

My objective is to apply the dictionary "di" to the dataframe, and replace the substring "EU" in the column "APPROACH" depending on the value in column "NATIONALITY". For instance, if the nationality equals "Germany", "EU" should be replaced with "DE". Ultimately, I aim to receive the following output:

```
NATIONALITY APPROACH
0   Germany MADE_TEST
1   France  MAFR_TEST
```

What I have tried so far is using the loc function to conditionally replace the values:

```
df.loc[df['NATIONALITY']=="Germany", 'APPROACH'] = df['APPROACH'].replace({'EU': 'DE'}, regex=True)
```

Above works fine, but considering that I have a long list of countries, it would be much more efficient to employ a dictionary.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is the string `EU` always in the 3rd/4th characters?

Comment: Not always, but the string "EU" is unique in that it only appears once in the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always have the `EU` string in a fixed location (here characters 2-3), then a simple [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and string concatenation is the most efficient:

```
df['APPROACH'] = (df['APPROACH'].str[:2]
                 +df['NATIONALITY'].map(di)
                 +df['APPROACH'].str[4:]
                 )
```

If not, then you need to loop over the pairs and replace the string with [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) (or a regex):

```
df['APPROACH'] = [a.replace('EU', di[n]) for n, a in
                  zip(df['NATIONALITY'], df['APPROACH'])]

# or, with regex
import re

df['APPROACH'] = [re.sub('EU', di[n], a) for n, a in
                  zip(df['NATIONALITY'], df['APPROACH'])]
```

*NB. if you know there is only 1 occurrence of `EU`, improve efficiency bu setting the max number of replacements '`a.replace('EU', di[n], 1)`).*

###### alternative for groups

If you have multiple repetitions of a given nationality, you can improve upon the loop approach using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['APPROACH'] = (df.groupby('NATIONALITY')['APPROACH']
                    .transform(lambda g: g.str.replace('EU', di[g.name]))
                 )
```

*NB. this should be more efficient that the list comprehension **if you have large groups**. To be tested on the real dataset.*

Output:

```
  NATIONALITY   APPROACH
0     Germany  MADE_TEST
1      France  MAFR_TEST
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted - thank you mozway!

Answer (score 1):

There is also the approach that consists in replacing the occurrences as such

```
>>> di = {'France': 'MAFR_TEST', 'Germany': 'MADE_TEST'}
>>> df.APPROACH = df.apply(axis=1, func=lambda s: di[s.NATIONALITY])
>>> df
  NATIONALITY   APPROACH
0     Germany  MADE_TEST
1      France  MAFR_TEST
```

That being shown, this is done on a country basis, which may be problematic if you have more that one APPROACH per country. Otherwise, as simple, you can do

```
di = {
    'France': {
        'MAEU_TEST': 'MAFR_TEST'
        # forthcoming other FR approaches
    },
    'Germany': {
        'MAEU_TEST': 'MADE_TEST'
        # forthcoming other DE approaches
    }
}
df.APPROACH = df.apply(
    axis=1, func=lambda s: (
        di[s.NATIONALITY].get(s.APPROACH, 'not-found')
    )
)
```

which returns

```
  NATIONALITY   APPROACH
0     Germany  MADE_TEST
1      France  MAFR_TEST
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks! But my problem focuses much more on replacing substrings.

Comment: Also you wouldn't use `apply` for that but `map`: `df['APPROACH'] = df['NATIONALITY'].map(di)`

Comment: True but your map approch is not trivially generalizabe, i.e. it does not allow for multiple approaches per country @mozway. It is also risky since it replaces things independently from the APPROACH's values being replaced.

Comment: @keepAlive yes it would using a `groupby`: `df['APPROACH'] = df.groupby('NATIONALITY')['APPROACH'].transform(lambda g: g.map(di.get(g.name, {})))` ;)

Comment: Still risky isn'it @moz ? Since it replaces things independently from the APPROACH's values being replaced. As risky as my non-generalized approach though. I can see you finding an other way of doing this :)

Comment: I don't understand your remark. Anyway I was commenting on the fact that `apply` should not be used and could be replaced by `map` (or `replace`) and I don't think that using a dictionary of hard-coded values is the way to go ;)

Comment: I do not get your comment @moz, ok for `pd.DataFrame.apply` that can be slow. But the "harcoded things" ? Your `re.sub`  approach contains as hard-coded pieces as mine, putting aside the string-indexing you initiated your answer with, as fragile as risky.

Comment: No, my approach replaces all `EU` by `FR`/`DE` based on the country. If the input string is `other_string_with_EU_` this will give `other_string_with_FR_`/`other_string_with_DE_`. Yours hardcodes the `'MAEU_TEST': 'MAFR_TEST'` substitution, which wouldn't work in a generic case.

Comment: True @moz. My answer starts by saying that incidentally : *occurrences as such*. Which annihilates the possibility of bad surprises. Following your risky approach, what would arrive with e.g.  [`other_EULOGIZING`](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-start-with-eu) ?  ...`other_FRLOGIZING` ? Even if I admit that you could regex things in such cases, regexing would collapse the generalized aspect of the sub-based replacement.